# Need a CudaMiner release

Tags: mining-software

I'm trying to mine with my gtx770 but now I know that I need the  "cudaMiner 2013-11-01". I've searched on the entire web (well only google but you know it has everything on the web) and all links are down, so if someone has the relase I'll appreciate it